# Web audio MediaElementSource node not being garbage collected

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

In web audio, is there a trick to getting MediaElementSource nodes to be garbage collected?

I've set up a page that adds two nodes: a MediaElementSource and an Oscillator. When I disconnect both of them, the Oscillator is garbage collected soon after, but the MediaElementSource stays permanently. (This is according to Firefox web audio dev tools which visualize the audio graph.)

I'm experiencing this in both Chrome and Firefox on Mac (Yosemite).

Why is the MediaElementSource node lingering permanently and is there any way to get rid of it without reloading the page or killing the audio context?

```
<audio src="gam2.mp3" id="audio" controls></audio>
<button onclick="disc()">disconnect</button>

<script>

    var actx = new AudioContext()

    var audio = document.getElementById("audio")
    var stream = actx.createMediaElementSource(audio)
    stream.connect(actx.destination)

    var sine = actx.createOscillator()
    sine.connect(actx.destination)

    function disc() {
        audio.remove()
        stream.disconnect()
        sine.disconnect()
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try nulling your var's so that the GC knows that they are eligible for garbage collection.

```
function disc() {
    audio.remove()
    stream.disconnect()
    stream = null
    sine.disconnect()
    sine = null //doing this here for consistency
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does not solve the issue. Strange, eh?